# outputs loss = nan and accuracy = 1

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to make a neural network for a classification problem. The training set takes 225 input of 48 dimensions and has a validation set of 50. the code is:

```
#building model
def build_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(128, activation = "relu"))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(64, activation = "relu"))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(32, activation = "relu"))
    model.add(Dropout(0.1))
    model.add(Dense(16, activation = "softmax"))

    model.compile(
        optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.00001),
        loss=['mean_squared_error'],
        metrics=['accuracy']
    )
    return model


model = build_model()


#train model
history = model.fit(
    x_train,
    y_train,
    epochs=10,
    batch_size=32,
    validation_data=(
        x_val,
        y_val
    ),
    callbacks=[ProgbarLogger(count_mode='steps',stateful_metrics=None)
    ]
)
```

but i get as output weird logs such as :

```
Train on 225 samples, validate on 50 samples
Epoch 1/10
Epoch 1/10
8/8 [==============================] - 2s 247ms/step - loss: 0.6517 - accuracy: 0.0178 - val_loss: 0.2842 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
225/225 [==============================] - 2s 9ms/sample - loss: 0.7298 - accuracy: 0.0178 - val_loss: 0.2842 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/10
Epoch 2/10
8/8 [==============================] - 0s 10ms/step - loss: 0.6516 - accuracy: 0.0222 - val_loss: 0.2842 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
225/225 [==============================] - 0s 359us/sample - loss: 0.7297 - accuracy: 0.0222 - val_loss: 0.2842 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/10
Epoch 3/10
8/8 [==============================] - 0s 9ms/step - loss: 0.6517 - accuracy: 0.0222 - val_loss: 0.2842 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
225/225 [==============================] - 0s 341us/sample - loss: 0.7297 - accuracy: 0.0222 - val_loss: 0.2842 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/10
Epoch 4/10
8/8 [==============================] - 0s 10ms/step - loss: 0.6515 - accuracy: 0.0178 - val_loss: 0.2842 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
225/225 [==============================] - 0s 346us/sample - loss: 0.7296 - accuracy: 0.0178 - val_loss: 0.2842 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 5/10
Epoch 5/10
8/8 [==============================] - 0s 9ms/step - loss: 0.7457 - accuracy: 0.0133 - val_loss: 0.2842 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
225/225 [==============================] - 0s 319us/sample - loss: 0.7295 - accuracy: 0.0133 - val_loss: 0.2842 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 6/10
Epoch 6/10
8/8 [==============================] - 0s 10ms/step - loss: 1.0552 - accuracy: 0.0133 - val_loss: 0.2842 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
225/225 [==============================] - 0s 359us/sample - loss: 0.7296 - accuracy: 0.0133 - val_loss: 0.2842 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 7/10
Epoch 7/10
8/8 [==============================] - 0s 9ms/step - loss: 0.6514 - accuracy: 0.0089 - val_loss: 0.2842 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
225/225 [==============================] - 0s 328us/sample - loss: 0.7295 - accuracy: 0.0089 - val_loss: 0.2842 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 8/10
Epoch 8/10
8/8 [==============================] - 0s 9ms/step - loss: 0.6516 - accuracy: 0.0133 - val_loss: 0.2842 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
225/225 [==============================] - 0s 324us/sample - loss: 0.7295 - accuracy: 0.0133 - val_loss: 0.2842 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 9/10
Epoch 9/10
8/8 [==============================] - 0s 10ms/step - loss: 0.6515 - accuracy: 0.0222 - val_loss: 0.2842 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
225/225 [==============================] - 0s 355us/sample - loss: 0.7296 - accuracy: 0.0222 - val_loss: 0.2842 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 10/10
Epoch 10/10
8/8 [==============================] - 0s 9ms/step - loss: 0.6515 - accuracy: 0.0267 - val_loss: 0.2842 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
225/225 [==============================] - 0s 328us/sample - loss: 0.7295 - accuracy: 0.0267 - val_loss: 0.2842 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
```

can you help me understand this behavior of the losses and the excess of accuracy. shouldnt it be lower?

Comment: By practice, you should not use ReLU, Sigmoid and Softmax functions together. If you are doing classification, the internal layers must use ReLU and the output layer must use the softmax activation function to produce class probabilities.

Comment: but i use softmax only o the last one